# How to let a C++ function return different types?

Tags: c++, templates

Look at this code:

```
#include<iostream>

enum class DataStructure{stack,queue};

template <typename T>
T foo(DataStructure ds){
  if(ds == DataStructure::stack){
    return 1;
  }
  else if(ds == DataStructure::queue){
    return 3.14F;
  }
}

int main(){
  std::cout<<foo(DataStructure::stack);
}
```

Obviously it does not compile, giving `error: no matching function for call to ‘foo(DataStructure)’`

But you understand what I want to do, is there a way to do that? Basically `foo` must return a different object or fundamental type depending on the value of the `enum`.

I apologize for the basic question.

Comment: "Basically foo must return a different object or fundamental type depending on the value of the enum. " Why? What *problem do you hope to solve* in this way? And how is the calling code supposed to know what it will receive, and deal with it accordingly?

Comment: Not sure what you want to accomplish with this, but it looks like you have a wrong assumption: Templates only work at compile time! You won't be able to return different types at runtime based on a enum value.

Comment: Consider the following: `void g(DataStructure ds) { Type t = foo(ds); }`. What should `Type` be to make it correct?

Comment: `But you understand what I want to do` no, I don't, neither anyone else would. I can make assumptions based on provided code, which might be completely wrong. That's the nature of XY question, you have a problem X for which you believe that you have to do Y, so you ask how to do that Y. Y might be impossible or indefinite without knowing the nature of X, so no one can tell you how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the passed in enum is a compile-time constant you can pass it as a template parameter and make the function return different types accordingly.

```
#include<iostream>

enum class DataStructure{stack,queue};

template <DataStructure T>
auto foo(){
  if constexpr (T == DataStructure::stack){
    return 1;
  }
  else if constexpr (T == DataStructure::queue){
    return 3.14F;
  }
}

int main(){
  std::cout<<foo<DataStructure::stack>();
}
```

Requires c++17 for the `if constexpr`, but you can achieve the same thing with a template specialization in earlier versions.

Answer (score 2):

Try [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant). It can return different values in runtime. It could look something [like this](https://godbolt.org/z/K1GEhr4Ef).

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

enum class DataStructure{stack,queue};

std::variant<int, double> foo(DataStructure ds){
  if(ds == DataStructure::stack){
    return 1;
  }
  else if(ds == DataStructure::queue){
    return 3.14F;
  }
}

// Updated version
int main(){
  std::visit(
      [](auto value) {
          std::cout << value;
      }, foo(DataStructure::stack));
}
```

```cpp
// Version without visit
int main(){
  auto value = foo(DataStructure::stack);
  if (std::holds_alternative<double>(value)) 
  {
    std::cout << get<double>(value);
  }
  else {
    std::cout << get<int>(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: For usage, [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) is better: `std::visit([](auto e){ std::cout << e; }, foo(DataStructure::stack));`

Comment: @Jarod42 You're right that syntax in sweet :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) which allows you to attach type-safe data to your various cases.

Answer (score 0):

Tagged dispatch:

```
struct queue {};
struct stack {};

int foo(stack) { return 1; }
float foo(queue) { return 3.14f; }

int main() {
    std::cout << foo(stack{}) << '\n';
    std::cout << foo(queue{}) << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare foo's variable type because you are using a template this may solve your problem because your function return's double:

```
 std::cout << foo<double> (DataStructure::stack);
```